Is there a Workaround To Creating Triggers in MySQL Using Prepared Statements
I am attempting to automate the creation of audit tables within a MySQL database. I have created a script that will automatically create an audit table with proper columns and data types for every table in a given schema that does not have one. For example of my database schema has a table called my_table the script will create another table called audit_my_table. Now I would like to add triggers to my_table so that whenever data is inserted or modified a record is created in the audit table. I have recently learned that prepared statements in MySQL do not allow the CREATE TRIGGER command. My knowledge with MySQL and SQL in general is pretty niche so I'm not currently aware if there is a suitable workaround that can get the same result. For context I will include the code that creates the audit tables.
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CreateAuditTriggers;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE CreateAuditTriggers(IN schemaName VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
    -- Declare variables
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tblName VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE auditTblName VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE colName VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE colType VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE triggerSQL LONGTEXT;

    -- Declare cursors
    DECLARE tblCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT t.table_name
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
        WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = schemaName
          AND t.TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'audit_%';

    DECLARE colCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT column_name, column_type
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_schema = schemaName
          AND table_name = tblName;

    -- Declare handlers
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
        SET done = TRUE;

    -- Open table cursor
    OPEN tblCursor;

    -- Loop through each table
    tbl_loop: LOOP
        FETCH tblCursor INTO tblName;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE tbl_loop;
        END IF;

        -- Set the audit table name
        SET auditTblName = CONCAT('audit_', tblName);

        -- Check if the audit table exists
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = schemaName 
              AND TABLE_NAME = auditTblName) = 0 THEN
            -- Audit table does not exist, skip this table
            ITERATE tbl_loop;
        END IF;

        -- Start generating the trigger SQL
        SET triggerSQL = CONCAT('
            CREATE TRIGGER ', tblName, '_before_insert
            BEFORE INSERT ON ', tblName, '
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO ', auditTblName, ' (');

        -- Open column cursor
        OPEN colCursor;

        -- Loop through columns to generate SQL
        col_loop: LOOP
            FETCH colCursor INTO colName, colType;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE col_loop;
            END IF;

            -- Add column to trigger SQL
            SET triggerSQL = CONCAT(triggerSQL, colName, ', ');
        END LOOP;

        -- Close column cursor
        CLOSE colCursor;

        -- Finalize trigger SQL
        SET triggerSQL = TRIM(TRAILING ', ' FROM triggerSQL);
        SET triggerSQL = CONCAT(triggerSQL, ') VALUES (');

        -- Re-open column cursor to append values
        OPEN colCursor;
        col_loop: LOOP
            FETCH colCursor INTO colName, colType;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE col_loop;
            END IF;

            -- Add column values to trigger SQL
            SET triggerSQL = CONCAT(triggerSQL, 'NEW.', colName, ', ');
        END LOOP;

        -- Close column cursor
        CLOSE colCursor;

        -- Finalize the trigger SQL
        SET triggerSQL = TRIM(TRAILING ', ' FROM triggerSQL);
        SET triggerSQL = CONCAT(triggerSQL, '); END;');

        -- Execute the trigger creation SQL
        SET @sql = triggerSQL;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        -- Reset done flag for the next iteration
        SET done = FALSE;
    END LOOP;

    -- Close table cursor
    CLOSE tblCursor;
END //

DELIMITER ;


I can think of two workarounds:
Workaround 1.
Use a client language, not the stored procedure language. This allows you to format your CREATE TRIGGER statement all at once as a string in your client language, and execute it. You don't have to prepare and execute if you do that. Whereas in the stored procedure language, there is no execute-immediate function; all you can do to write a dynamic statement is to use prepare and execute.
In fact, I regularly recommend to avoid using the MySQL stored procedure language for any task.
Workaround 2.
Instead of using triggers, use the MySQL audit log plugin. This may be more versatile, secure, and performant than using triggers.
The audit plugin provided by MySQL is available only to enterprise customers, but there are free, open source implementations too, such as the Percona Audit Log Plugin.
